# Searchable encryption method (for a dummy!)

Tags: javascript, database, search, encryption, indexeddb

I am attempting to 'secure' (as I know it won't be very secure) the data in a indexedDB on the client side for an **OFFLINE WEB APP** (i.e. anyone who is attempting to access the data will be able to see the encryption method used so I am aware that makes brute force pretty damned easy!)

I am going to encrypt it using the Username and Password as that is the only thing I could possibly keep secret.

There are loads of ways to do this, however I have one requirement that has me stumped - I need to maintain the ability to be able to search the database.

Can anybody point me in the direction of how I can encrypt data but still be able to search it.

The encryption doesn't have to be bank-level security by any means, just want to protect the database in case a tablet etc. got lost so that 99% of people wouldn't be able to view the data directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my library, [ydn-db](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/usage/encryption.html). For encrypted, you can only search by primary key only thought.

Comment: Hi Kyaw Tun - funny you say that I AM using your library - it is excellent, unfortunately I cannot just search by primary key. I have a method I am working on, but being no expert on cryptography I have a feeling it will make you weep, will post it here when I am done so you can pass judgement.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie you should able to search by primary key.